# How to check currently installed web3 version?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ubuntu

How to check installed web3 version with command line terminal?

Comment: This message has nothing to do with `web3`, it's telling you to upgrade `npm` itself.

Comment: the message suggests to update your `npm` no web3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From a command line: `npm ls web3` or `npm list web3`.

By the way, this message has nothing to do with `web3`, it's telling you to upgrade `npm` itself.

Comment: thanx @goodvibration my problem solved upgrading npm

Answer (score 10):

`npm install web3` installs web3.js, which has a version command documented here:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3versionapi

```
var version = web3.version.api;
console.log(version); // "0.2.0"
```

Comment: Or just `npm ls web3`

Comment: shows different version than package.json

Answer (score 2):

Update for 2020:

It's just `Web3.version`

E.g.

```
console.log(Web3.version);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your node module versions using:

```
npm view <module> version
```

So just type on your terminal:

```
npm view web3 version
```

Answer (score 0):

You may by the following:

**Step-I:** on your console write "node" and then *enter*

```
~/../currentDir> node
```

Then:

```
>var Web3 = require("web3");
>console.log(Web3.version);
```

Output:

```
'1.2.11' //version
```