# how to deal with bytes32 to string in javascript?

Tags: solidity

I am going to set a email address from users and going to save it to ethereum network.

I kept email as bytes32 in smart contract and when I am sending the value to javascript i am getting always a same bytes . when i use to convert to ascii I am getting '@' everytime. what can be the reason?

Comment: In the smart contract, you write a (hard-coded) string literal, for example, "me@gmail.com"?

Comment: Or are you sending this value from the off-chain (Javascript) to the contract?

Comment: off-chain from user inputed value

Answer (score 3):

If you're on web3 v0.x, then:

- Use [`web3.fromAscii`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3fromascii) before you send the string to the smart contract
- Use [`web3.toAscii`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii) after you read the string from the smart contract

If you're on web3 v1.x, then:

- Use [`web3.utils.asciiToHex`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#asciitohex) before you send the string to the smart contract
- Use [`web3.utils.hexToAscii`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#hextoascii) after you read the string from the smart contract

Comment: how can i see the verson of web3

Comment: @RaonakIslamNiloy: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/51020/16043